# Display text above using phtml code

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, product-view

we are using [custom module](https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions/tree/master/Magento%20Display%20Shipping%20estimation%20Block%20in%20Product%20view%20page) for displaying shipping charges in Product View page.

Means once we enter the zip code in view page,

1)it will calculate the shipping charges & 
2)it will display shipping is available or not as [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/full-of-power-chhota-bheem-mug.html) , [zip : 110001]

[image]

If you observe clearly ,you can see "Shipping is available" is not displaying properly in above image. so i want to move the text above and want to display as here :

[image]

I am using following code to display shipping charges and message :

```
<p class="vship1">
<?php echo "Selling Price + " . str_replace('.00','',$_excl) . " Delivery & Shipping is available";?>
</p>
```

complete code of the results.phtml :

```
<div class="block block-shipping-estimate block-shipping-results">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span>
        <?php 
    echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getShiptitle(); 
        ?>
        </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
<?php if ($this->getResult()):?>
        <dl>
            <?php foreach ($this->getResult() as $code => $_rates): ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                        <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                           <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <?php echo $_rate->getErrorMessage() ?>
                           <?php else: ?>
                                <?php 
                            //  echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() 
                                ?>
                                <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>

                                <p class="vship1">
                                <?php echo "Selling Price + " . str_replace('.00','',$_excl) . " Delivery & Shipping is available";?>
                                </p>


                                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                    (<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                <?php endif; ?>
                           <?php endif ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php //echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getResult(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>



<style>

.vship1
{
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;


}



</style>
```

Comment: I think your question is related to css

Comment: @Arunendra thanks for your comment. Below answer helped me to fix the issue using phtml.

Comment: I have just suggested for you  :)

Comment: oh, Thanks a lot @Arunendra  for your support :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `top: 110px;` from the css. add code like that you can achieve you requirement

```
<p >
                                    <?php echo "Shipping is available";?>
                                    </p>

<p class="vship1">
                                <?php echo "Selling Price + " . str_replace('.00','',$_excl) . " Delivery & ";?>
                                </p>
.vship1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
}
```

Comment: If i remove that than , complete `Selling Price + Rs. 0 Delivery & Shipping is available` line will display above

but i want to move up only this text "Shipping is available"

Comment: update answer check it and feedback

Comment: Thanks, This is what i wanted, needed solution using phtml code.